# Join statement with condition in sql

Tags: sql, join, conditional-statements

```
a.geosid    a.Latitude   a.Longitude    b.Latitude  b.Longitude     b.geosid
9589565     -36.013472  -71.426018      -36.0135    -71.426         9589565
9586071     -36.015     -71.498         -36.1104    -71.4416        9586071
9589565     -36.013473  -71.426017      -36.0135    -71.426         9589565
```

The data above is formed by running a query in sql something like

```
SELECT *
FROM   [ChileCSVimports].[dbo].[tLocation] a
       JOIN AIRGeography..tGeography b
         ON a.GeographySID = b.GeographySID
```

I need to select data such that the two lat-long of two different tables if they differ by 0.0002 (respectively) or more then don't select the data --

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds fairly straightforward, since they're both numbers. Since you're using an inner join, you can either put the criteria in the join:

```
SELECT *
FROM   [ChileCSVimports].[dbo].[tLocation] a
       JOIN AIRGeography..tGeography b
         ON a.GeographySID = b.GeographySID
         AND ABS(a.Latitude - b.Latitude) < 0.0002
         AND ABS(a.Longitude - b.Longitude) < 0.0002
```

... or in a separate WHERE clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM   [ChileCSVimports].[dbo].[tLocation] a
       JOIN AIRGeography..tGeography b
         ON a.GeographySID = b.GeographySID
WHERE    ABS(a.Latitude - b.Latitude) < 0.0002
         AND ABS(a.Longitude - b.Longitude) < 0.0002
```

Either way, simply let the DB server do the math while retrieving your result set. This ABS() function is available on most DBMSes with identical syntax; PostgreSQL uses the "@" operator as a shorthand (`@ -5.4` evaluates to `5.4`).

Comment: For something this close to general reference, that's to be expected. The answers all differ slightly; my answer ended up a combination of the two of yours. We'll let the OP decide which one gets the check.

Comment: That's not quite the point.  Supplying an answer that's essentially the same answers already supplied is generally not recommended.  This adds nothing to the existing answers and should really have been deleted imho . . .

Comment: He who types fastest does not necessarily know best. I started writing this answer when there were none, and the fact that two answers were posted  while I was writing mine does not mean the information in my answer is bad or wrong, or that I'm an evil person for hitting the post button myself. It simply means the question was easy enough to answer that the community flocked to it. SO is a community system; the fact there are multiple similar answers indicates a community consensus. If it's so vitally important to you that the first to post a correct answer gets the credit then go on Jeopardy.

Comment: As far as deleting, I delete answers when the information in them is proven wrong and as a result there's no hope of saving the post, or if by that point the question has been answered correctly by another. This situation is neither, and so even if I could delete it now, I wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can add to your `JOIN` criteria or use `WHERE` criteria to compare the values:

```
SELECT *
FROM   [ChileCSVimports].[dbo].[tLocation] a
       JOIN AIRGeography..tGeography b
         ON a.GeographySID = b.GeographySID 
        AND ABS(a.Latitude - b.Latitude) < 0.0002 
        AND ABS(a.Longitude - b.Longitude) < 0.0002
```

Use `ABS()` to return the absolute value so you don't have to worry about which value is bigger than the other.

Comment: Again Identical answer :D

Answer (score 1):

Add the filters in `where` clause. Try this.

```
SELECT *
FROM   [ChileCSVimports].[dbo].[tLocation] a
       JOIN AIRGeography..tGeography b
         ON a.GeographySID = b.GeographySID 
Where ABS(a.Latitude - b.Latitude) < 0.0002  
and   ABS(a.Longitude - b.Longitude) <0.0002
```